# HTTP request doesn't get complete data in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have this class :

```
class Weeks {
final int index;
  final int udigree;
  final int d_id;
  final String activity_a;
  final String activity_k;
  final String title_a;
  final String title_k;
  Weeks(this.index, this.udigree, this.d_id, this.activity_a, this.activity_k,
      this.title_a, this.title_k);
}
```

I used future function to get data from server :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jiyanUquraan/classes/weekly.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
class Weekly extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WeeklyState createState() => _WeeklyState();
}
class _WeeklyState extends State<Weekly> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var widthView = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var heightView = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    List weekly = [];
    Map rData = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    var cm_id = rData['current_m_id'];
    var u_id = rData['u_id'];
    var d_id = rData['d_id'];
    var w_id = rData['w_id'];
    // Futher Function for Get Data
    Future<List> getWeeks() async {
      print(cm_id);
      print(u_id);
      print(w_id);
      var url =
          'http://10.0.2.2/jiyan/test/api/digrees/weekly_report.php?m_id=$cm_id&u_id=$u_id&w_id=$w_id';
      var response = await http.get(url);
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data);
      print(data.length);
      for (var x in data) {
        Weeks _weeklyReport = Weeks(x['index'], x['udigree'], x['activity_a'],
            x['activity_k'], x['title_a'], x['title_k'], x['d_id']);
        weekly.add(_weeklyReport);
      }
      return weekly;
    }
    // End of Get Data
    // Create Future Builder
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getWeeks(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Loading'),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: Text('data'));
          }
        });
    // End of Futur Builder
  }
}
```

As I print the data and its length, the length is correct but the data is not complete as shown:

[image: img]

As it doesn't get the data correctly the `snapshot.data` gets null, How can I fix this?
Does the error occur because the data is Kurdish?

Comment: it is because `print` methode has some charactor length. If you realy want to print each and every one print  one by one within the `for  loop`.

Comment: @Sajith and why snapshot.data get null?

Comment: I think your implementation is wrong . follow this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: i used same in other page and it works correctly

Comment: I solved it by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Mistake was in the class .
the variables d_id and udigree must be String

```
class Weeks {
final int index;
  final String udigree;
  final Stringd_id;
  final String activity_a;
  final String activity_k;
  final String title_a;
  final String title_k;
  Weeks(this.index, this.udigree, this.d_id, this.activity_a, this.activity_k,
      this.title_a, this.title_k);
}
```